# Could not find method lintChecks()

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

When I add `lintChecks project(':checks')` to my module's `build.gradle` like the following:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/dependencies.gradle"

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    lintChecks project(':checks')

    // Libraries
    implementation libs.arrow.core
    implementation libs.javaxInject
    implementation libs.kotlin.stdlib
    implementation libs.moshi.core
    implementation libs.moshi.adapters
    implementation libs.rxjava.core
    implementation libs.rxjava.kotlin

    // Test Dependencies
    testImplementation libs.truth
    testImplementation libs.spek.dsl
    testRuntimeOnly libs.spek.runner
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'spek'
    }
}
```

I receive:

`Could not find method lintChecks() for arguments [project ':checks'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Does anyone know what could resolve this? I'm trying to implement custom lint checks and I have been following the [Google code examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules) to a tee.

Comment: Grant there is no project with name 'checks'.  We need to create custom lints and use that in our project using lintchecks.                                                                       https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#new_features

Comment: Which version of gradle plugin for android are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti 3.4.1

Comment: @RanjanKumar I have a separate co-existing module named "checks" that contains my custom linting code. It is almost an exact copy of what you see in the Google sample repo.  

The code block in my post represents the `build.gradle` for a co-existing Kotlin module named "lib" that wants to apply the custom linting from "checks"

Comment: OK. This link https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#new_features suggests to use 'lintPublish'.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use built-in 'lint-checks' and i was also getting similar error.
But when i used lintPublish it worked.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    lintPublish 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks'
}
```